# I wold like to adjust the axis of my radar graph giving to each parameter the values of the variables

Tags: python, radar-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjoE4.png)
this is my current graph and i wold like to adjust like this one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8stn.png)
demonstrating in each parameter the values ​​for each of the data groups

i was trying adding ax.set_rgrids([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]) but it only changes the overall

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.